# Resharper and Productivity Power Tools fight over my usings. How can I stop the bloodshed?

Tags: c#, resharper, using-statement, productivity-power-tools, xml-documentation

Here's the type of code that starts the violence:

```
public interface ISomething
{
   /// <exception cref="IOException" />
   void DoSomethingWithTheFilesystem();
}
```

Resharper 9.2 sees this and suggests (insists) that I add a `using System.IO` for `IOException` with a blue underline and a pop-over message that I can't dismiss. However, since this is an interface, I don't have an actual code reference to `IOException`, and I have Productivity Power Tools configured to remove unused usings when files are saved. So as soon as I save the document, PPT deletes the using. Which makes R# complain again the next time I open it (or do code analysis). Automatically adding usings when you add code is a very useful feature. So is automatically removing them when you delete it. Is there something I can do to make peace between these two factions without sacrificing one or the other?

Comment: I don't know of a solution, but I find this question amusing.

Comment: question is funny......bloodshed :D

Comment: I think there is way to supress resharper error

Comment: What happens if you use /// <exception cref="System.IO.IOException" /> ?

Comment: @Viru I could, but the R# feature is useful in other circumstances when I really do need to have the using.

Comment: @MetroSmurf That works around it (and is obvious in retrospect :smacks forehead:). I wish I didn't have to, but that's probably the best answer I'm going to get.

Comment: It's probably actually better that you use the fully qualified name anyway. The documentation should be complete in place, without depend on using statements.

Comment: @siride A legitimate point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comment as a suggestion which worked, I'll repost here as the answer.

Use the fully qualified namespace to maintain peace amongst the factions. As mentioned in the comments by @siride, this is "probably actually better that you use the fully qualified name anyway. The documentation should be complete in place, without depend on using statements."

```
/// <exception cref="IOException" />
```

Becomes:

```
/// <exception cref="System.IO.IOException" />
```